# different substring for each row based on condition

Tags: pandas

How do one add a different substring to each row based on a condition in pandas?

Here is a dummy dataframe that I created:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 2)))
df.columns = ['A','B']
```

If I replace the rows in `B`, with a string `YYYY` for those rows which have the value in `A` less then 5, then I would do it this way:

```
df.loc[df['A'] < 2, 'B'] = 'YYYY'
```

This is the current output of original df:

```
   A  B
0  3  4
1  0  1
2  3  0
3  0  1
4  4  4
```

Of replaced df:

```
   A     B
0  3     4
1  0  YYYY
2  3     0
3  0  YYYY
4  4     4
```

What I instead want is:

```
   A     B
0  3     4
1  0    1_1
2  3     0
3  0    1_2
4  4     4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is necessary generate list with same size like number of `True`s values with `range` and `sum`, then convert to strings and join together:

```
m = df['A'] < 2
df.loc[m, 'B'] = df.loc[m, 'B'].astype(str) + '_' + list(map(str, range(1, m.sum() + 1)))

print (df)
   A    B
0  3    4
1  0  1_1
2  3    0
3  0  1_2
4  4    4
```

Or you can use `f-string`s for generate new list:

```
m = df['A'] < 2
df.loc[m, 'B'] = [f'{b}_{a}' for a, b in zip(range(1, m.sum() + 1), df.loc[m, 'B'])]
```

EDIT1:

```
m = df['A'] < 4
df.loc[m, 'B'] = df.loc[m, 'B'].astype(str) + '_' + df[m].groupby('B').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)

print (df)
   A    B
0  3  4_1
1  0  1_1
2  3  0_1
3  0  1_2
4  4    4
```

Comment: this solves my problem, but an extension to this could be the following:
`1_1`, and `1_2`, and `4_1` and `4_2` if the mask condition was set to 4

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, your first answer solved the problem. I was merely suggesting a addition. I appreciate your effort :)